How to add multiple entries in a alias in Nu Shell?
I was wondering if there is any way to have something like:
alias system = sudo vpm sync; sudo vpm update; sudo vpm autoremove; sudo vpm cleanup

This is possible in bash --even in fish.
I was not able to find anything relevant in the documentation.

I'd suggest a command definition here rather than an alias

Why not use a function instead? https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/def.html

@pmf: I tried, it worked but it is not persistent

@OneCricketeer: Something persistent?

@Georgios Then save it and source it? Or use one of login.nu, env.nu, or config.nu in the standard configuration directory for an "autoload" effect.

@pmf: Perfect! Thank you both very much.
